# Conversion from HTML to Joomla is not working

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I am new to **Joomla** and I am customizing theme from HTML to joomla 3.My folder structure is like

--mysite
  |
   --CSS
   --Images
   --index.php
   --index.html
   --templateDetails.xml

**index.php**:

```
    <?php

    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

    $doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    $doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
    $doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js');
    $doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js');

    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

     <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
        <jdoc:include type="head" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/css/templatemo_style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--
    This is a free CSS template provided by templatemo.com
    -->
    <div id="templatemo_container_wrapper">
        <div class="templatemo_spacer"></div>
    <div id="templatemo_container">
    <div id="templatemo_top"> <a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Website Templates</a> · <a href="http://www.flashmo.com/" target="_parent">Flash Templates</a> · <a href="#">Company</a> · <a href="#">Contact</a></div>
      <div id="templatemo_header">
          <div id="inner_header">
            <jdoc:include type="component" />
          </div>
      </div>

          <div id="templatemo_left_column">
            <div class="section_box2" align="justify">
            <div class="text_area">
            <img src="images/s_flashmo_022_park_34.jpg" alt="Photo One" title="Photo One" width="120" height="90" class="templatemo_pic" />
            <jdoc:include type="module" name="left" style="none" />
            </div>
            </div>



            </div>
          </div>

            <div id="templatemo_right_column">

                <ul class="templatemo_menu">
                    <jdoc:include type="module" name="right_menu" style="none" />
                </ul>

              <div class="section_box" align="justify">
                    <jdoc:include type="module" name="right_content" style="none" />
              </div>

        </div>

        <div id="templatemo_footer">
            <jdoc:include type="module" name="footer" style="none" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="templatemo_spacer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**templateDetails.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 2.5//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/2.5/template-install.dtd">
    <extension
        version="3.1"
        type="template"
        client="site">
        <name>MySite</name>
        <creationDate>01/10/2014</creationDate>
        <author>Rohil</author>
        <authorEmail>rohilmistry@xyz.com</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>rohilmistry.com</authorUrl>
        <copyright>Copyright Rohil</copyright>
        <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>Site Description goes here ...</description>
        <files>
            <folder>images</folder>
            <folder>css</folder>
            <filename>index.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        </files>

        <positions>
            <position>top_header</position>
            <position>left</position>
            <position>right_menu</position>
            <position>right_content</position>
            <position>footer</position>
        </positions>


    </extension>
```

And it is giving me [this output](http://1drv.ms/1tjgE9f) and I want to achieve [this](http://1drv.ms/1tjgNJN).

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: First step to find the problem is to use browser inspect tools to see if your css file is loaded.

Comment: After debugging I got [this much](http://1drv.ms/1tjjTh4).Right side Navigation Menu is missing and other content on right side.

Comment: I think it's because of the button placement, you could disable it to check.

Comment: From where can I disable it?

Comment: You could disable or hide elements from: `Content -> Article Manager -> Options`.

Comment: Sorry but not working ..

Comment: Can we please either stick to this question of the one on joomla.stackexchange. I'm unable to flag as a duplicate as they're on different sites but I would recommend deleting 1 of them to avoid confusion. As mentioned on your other question, could you possibly provide a zip file with your template so we can test?

Comment: Besides what Lodder said, you should answer your own question so that this is a useful question answer for someone else and if you have a different question post it on ONE site.